# Finding hashtags in a input string from a user

Tags: java, arrays

I am running a program that is supposed to be able to find every word starting with a hashtag and outputting it but I get thrown this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at userInput.readString(Menu.java:9)
    at Menu.main(Menu.java:198)
```

I am relatively new to Java so I am unsure how to fix this. Some input would be greately appreciated

My code:

```
class userInput{
        public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        public static String readString(String message){
            System.out.println(message);
            String readValue = input.nextLine();
            return readValue;
        }
    
        public static int readInt(String message){
            System.out.println(message);
            int readValue = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            return readValue;
        }
    
        public static double readDouble(String message){
            System.out.println(message);
            double readValue = input.nextDouble();
            input.nextLine();
            return readValue;
        }
    
        public static void close(){
            input.close();
        }
    }
    
     
    
     String post [] = new String [100];
                        String userPost = "";
                        userPost = userInput.readString("\nType your post");
                        post[0] = userPost;
                      
                        String hashtags ="";
                        for (int i = 0; i<post.length && post[i]!=null;i++){
                            String[]words = post[i].split(" ");
                                for(int j=0;j<words.length;j++){
                                    if(words[j].trim().startsWith("#")){
                                        hashtags+=words[j].trim() + " ";
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                        if(hashtags.trim().isEmpty())
                        System.out.println("No hashtags were typed");
                        else 
                            System.out.println("Hashtags found: " + hashtags );
```

Comment: @OldProgrammer - I think this is something different.  The question you reference involves getting an error when calling `nextInt()`.  Here, it is `nextLine()` that is failing.  It would be hard to get into it here, but the problem occurs with `nextInt()` shouldn't happen with `nextLine()`.  Instead, what you'll get is extra blank lines that you don't want or expect rather than an exception being thrown.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please go back into your question and property format your code.  If you're asking for help from others, it's disrespectful to not make your code as easy to read as possible.  Also, your code isn't complete.  The def of the `userInput` class is OK (name should be capitalized), but the code below that is not valid as it isn't in a method inside a class.  The lines of your code responsible for getting a line of input from the user seems OK. People often have trouble with Scanner if they're running their code in certain IDEs or via online compilers.  How are you running your code?

Comment: I am using visual studio code to write the program and it works there but when I use the online compiler Codegrade, it wont work. Should I post the whole code?

Comment: It's common for this to be a problem on an online site.  Some sites just don't properly support taking user input.  Some of the sites do take user input, but you have to enter all of your input into an "Input" box on the screen before you run your program.  Maybe that's true of Codegrade.  I know nothing about it.

Comment: SIDE NOTE:  This question is NOT a duplicate of the one cited as the reason for closing this question.  Check out the error message given in each question.  They're different, and that's significant.  The solution to the cited question won't solve this OPs problem.  I would be very surprised if there wasn't another question that is a proper duplicate of this question, so it doesn't matter much. I've answered these questions over and over, and only for that reason have gotten to know the quirks of Scanner (which I doubt I've ever used myself).